# Corona sdk "OR" operator

Tags: json, sdk, lua, coronasdk, operator-keyword

I am working on an app the returns a json table from a network request. When the user enters a 3 letter airport code and it gets returned in a newText object. If the type in the airport LAX the stateCode from the json file gets returned as CA but if the type in an airport code from a different country its returns an error because what has been returned doesnt have a stateCode.

So I tried to use the "or" operator in the following code.

```
display.newText(myData.airports[1].stateCode or myData.airports[1].countryCode)
```

How can I return the stateCode and if it doenst have a stateCode, return the countryCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
local textValue = myData.airports[1].stateCode or myData.airports[1].countryCode
```

and then you may use it as a value to a newText. If stateCode is `nil` or `false`, it will use countryCode.

Comment: You might want to add a third string, just in case both variables are nil (perhaps an airport your data has missed out):

local textValue = myData.airports[1].stateCode or myData.airports[1].countryCode or "Unknown airport"

Answer (score 0):

If your using this code inside any function,

```
display.newText(myData.airports[1].stateCode or myData.airports[1].countryCode)
```

Then you directly return like this,

```
return myData.airports[1].stateCode or myData.airports[1].countryCode
```

This will automatically return which ever value is available.

Comment: I'm not using it in a function. I'm creating various text display objects

Comment: How can I use i in a function?

Comment: Its better you share me part of the code which you want to modify.